# ¿ Cómo ejecutar un archivó html fuera de red local usando localhost.run?

Tags: html, archivo

¿ cómo ejecutar un archivó html fuera de red local usando localhost.run ?

`file:///sdcard/index.html`

¿algunas ideas? Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo usar un servidor apache o si no tienes mucha experiencia puedes usar MAMP, XAMPP O WAMP que ya lo tienen instalado, solo le das click al boton encender o apagar.